# Can't create a new Spree app: "undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks='"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, spree

I had this issue a couple of months ago, [posted it on Spree's GitHub page](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5448), then figured out the solution myself and posted it on that same issue. Two months later, I'm still getting comments on that same issue from Googlers who had the same error message, so I figure it's worth posting my solution on this website as well just in case anyone is having the same problem but isn't looking on GitHub.

The issue: trying to create a brand new Spree app, following the exact instructions in Spree's documentation, gives the following error when you try to run `spree install --auto-accept` or `rails g spree:install`:

```
undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Solution below...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined method raise\_in\_transactional\_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError) when generating scaffold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006358/undefined-method-raise-in-transactional-callbacks-for-activerecordbaseclass)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem: I'd created a new rails app with `rails new`, which had automatically created an app using `rails 4.2.0beta`. Then I had issues with gem incompatibilities, so I'd changed the version number of a few gems, including downgrading Rails back to `4.1.8`.

BUT the config setting `raise_in_transactional_callbacks` is **new in Rails 4.2.0**, so in earlier versions of Rails it will raise an error. If you're getting this error message you need to remove the line `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` from `config/application.rb`.

Comment: +1. This fixed it for me, but I'm curious why it's there by default now. Is it possible that removing it is actually the wrong thing to do?

Comment: Well, if you're using Rails < 4.2, you have no choice but to remove it, because it will raise an error. In Rails 4.2.x, the line is there to opt-in to a setting that will be made the default in Rails 5. If you remove the line in Rails 4.2 you'll get a deprecation warning.