# Undefined method raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Before writing this question I looked at these answers, but was unable to find a solution.:

[Error when execute rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874678/error-when-execute-rails-generate-scaffold-user-namestring-emailstring)

[rake aborted! undefined method `migration_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000712/rake-aborted-undefined-method-migration-error-for-activerecordbaseclass)

[Error launching Rails server: undefined method 'configure'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977051/error-launching-rails-server-undefined-method-configure)

---

When I try to start a new application (for  [Hartl's tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/), Chapter 2), at the stage *scaffold* start, I got an error like:

```
**undefined method `configure' for #<SampleApp2::Application:0x00000101a74610> (NoMethodError)**
```

But thanks to the above examples, I edited the *development.rb* file:

```
DemoApp::Application.configure do
```

(Yes, my application is called *demo_app* so I transformed its name).

After that, I tried to run *scaffold* again but got a new error:

```
**method_missing': undefined method raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)**
```

In response to similar cases indicates a *migration* method - that it should be removed from the file development.rb. Similarly, I tried to find in this file *raise_in_transactional_callbacks* method, but it's not there!
In addition, I would say that the full code that produces in cmd is very large:

```
C:\Sites\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
invoke  active_record
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:166:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:165:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
…
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Where the ...(ellipsis) - specially cut similar code.
That's all. I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Your `config/application.rb` has the following line:

`config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true`

This is not a valid configuration value in your version of Rails. You will need to delete it or comment it out to continue.

---

Note: this error and the one that preceded it are indicative of an incomplete [Rails version change](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html). If you are in the early stages of a tutorial, you might seriously consider restarting your application using your preferred version of Rails from the very start. This will help you avoid this type of error until you are more familiar with the technology.

Comment: Maybe it's useful to say that the line works with rails version >= 4.2

Comment: Proper answer and comment that completes it well.  Had created a 4.2 app, but needed to rollback to 4.1 for gem accessibility.  +1

Comment: This worked: I'm confused by the 'Note"...I'm not sure what else needs to be done when migrating to another version of rails.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Remember to run `rails app:update` after upgrading rails ;)

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue when upgrading an app from Rails 5.0.1 to Rails 5.1.0.beta1.

When starting the server (`rails s`), I got the following error message:

```
/home/user01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.beta1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Same ills, same cures.

Commenting out the following line, in `config/application.rb`, solved the issue...

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

After some investigation, I found that this line was default in Rails 4.2.1, vanished in Rails 5.0.0, and now raises an error in Rails 5.1.0.beta1...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` in `config/application.rb` it might exist in your environment configs. For my app it was being set it in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/test.rb`