# undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for #<Class:0x0000000460c328> when connecting to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just set up my rails development environment in linux and started a new rails app. When browsing to localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000 I get the error message:

```
undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for #<Class:0x0000000460c328>
```

I have not coded anything. This happened right after creating the app and browsing to localhost. What can I do to fix this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined method raise\_in\_transactional\_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError) when generating scaffold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006358/undefined-method-raise-in-transactional-callbacks-for-activerecordbaseclass)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your `config/application.rb` and comment the line:

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```