# Please help, undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for #<Class:0x007fc3b02ed058>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web-applications

I can't figure out what is going on. The app was working just a moment ago and after doing some editing it messed up. I rolled everything back as best as I could, but now I am getting this error. I would be infinitly grateful if someone could help, I have to present this as soon as possible. If anyone can help I would be infinitely grateful.

A link to the git repository: https://github.com/AceConcept/Todo-App

link to screenshot of the error: [image: Error]

Comment: Please add (to the question) any error messages you are getting.

Comment: Added a screen shot, if there is anything else I can do to help please let me know

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, but you should really add the error messages manually by text or cut/paste otherwise someone will downvote your question. Also I can't add anything else to what @Jason has already suggested below. Be sure to look at the link in his question. Also for future reference here is a [link](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition) to MHartl's source code for the final railstutorial app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

from **application.rb**.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008145/4443890)

Comment: I removed the line and the error still exists

Comment: Did you restart the server? I cloned your app, ran `bundle`, ran the app, tried `rake routes` and I got your error. I removed that line from **application.rb**, restarted the server, tried `rake routes` and the error was gone. I also played around with your app in my browser and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I didn't restart the server, now everything is working! Thank you!