# Heroku not authenticating; deploying heroku server issues; what's happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ide

I am having serious problems getting Heroku and github to work with me.

I notice that I do not get an authentication from Heroku once I put in my log in information:

```
heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: blank@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Logged in as blank@gmail.com
```

I do not get an authentication message, something my instructor said was very important. I have no idea why. I have everything set up correctly, including the proper ssh key, which I got via:

```
heroku keys:add
```

Then

```
heroku create
```

This is where things start really going wrong. I never get

```
Git remote heroku added
```

Instead, I just get

```
Creating app... done, stack is cedar-14
https://agile-lake-38079.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/agilelake-38079.git
```

With no indication of anything added.

After

```
git push origin master
```

and

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this same error every single time:

```
'Counting objects: 66, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (66/66), 16.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 66 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.5.0
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.1.0
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing actionview 4.1.0
remote:        Installing rack 1.5.5
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.1.0
remote:        Installing mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Installing polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Installing treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Installing mail 2.5.4
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.1.0
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.1.0
remote:        Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.1.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.1.0
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.0.0
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 3.1.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.11.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.2.19
remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Installing uglifier 1.3.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 46 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (40.23s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:108:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_8ed55ea28867430d1f1b83cfeabc180a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to agile-lake-38079.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-lake-38079.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-lake-38079.git''
```

I have tried altering the application.rb file, just in case, and I have also tweaked my Gemfile to make sure it has:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Neither have worked. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28008145/3896300

Comment: Thanks brother, that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Your authentication is fine :)

When you push to Heroku, it creates a slug of your application — think of it like a compressed, production-ready and production-tuned package.

Your problem lies when Heroku tries to create this slug. Your log outputs this line:

> remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `raise_in_transactional_callbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

Models inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, so that should tell you that it's something (very likely) in your model code.

Locally, you can run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` to see how Heroku would treat app.