# Does rails update affect my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

if I update rails from 4.2.5 to 5.0.0 on my pc, does it affect my app in any way? And if I update the Gemfile, changing rails 4.2.5 to rails 5.0.0 does it ruin my app or give me troubles? Thanks for the help

Comment: Upgrading **any** software can cause issues. If your app is small, then upgrading should be fairly easy. If your app is large, it may involve more work. This question is too vague; if you are having a **specific** problem/concern with the upgrade, then please submit it as a new question.

Comment: *"I'm upgrading to Windows 10. Will it affect my computer in any way? Will my it ruin my computer or give me troubles?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide for upgrading your Rails app from 4.2.5 to 5.0.0: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

This should tell you how to fix anything that would have broken by upgrading.

Also seems to be a duplicate of: [How to upgrade from rails 4.2.6 to rails 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442248/how-to-upgrade-from-rails-4-2-6-to-rails-5-0)