# Is it possible to upgrade Rails app separately in a different branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a working Rails 4.2+ app and I need to upgrade to 5.x because additional gems require minimum 5.x.x. This is my first experience in upgrading and I found some neat solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442248/how-to-upgrade-from-rails-4-2-6-to-rails-5-0). Is it safe to assume that if I create a new branch then make the changes there, it will not affect the other branches?

Another approach I'm thinking is downloading the master folder from the remote repository then do the mock upgrading there. Please advise me if there is a better and more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Yes you can do it in a different branch and it won't affect other branches, I'm currently doing that and have done it that way in the past

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new branch and it will not affect other branches. So to answer your question, go ahead and upgrade Rails!